# sum of integer parts of roots

Tags: calculus

> If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are real roots of the equation $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-2} = \frac{11}{54}x^2.$ Then $\lfloor \alpha \rfloor + \lfloor \beta \rfloor +\lfloor \gamma \rfloor $

$\bf{Attempt}$ From equation $$\frac{x^2-3x+2+x^2-2x+x^2-x}{x(x-1)(x-2)} = \frac{11}{54}x^2$$

So $$\frac{3x^2-6x+2}{x^3-3x^2+2x} = \frac{11}{54}x^2$$

$$162x^2-324x+108 = 11x^5-33x^4+22x^3$$

$$11x^5-33x^4+22x^3-162x^2+324x-108 =0$$

Could some help me how to solve it, thanks

Comment: Result is $0+1+3=4$ and I do not see any other then numerical way to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\ge 3$, then the LHS is $\le \frac13+\frac12+1=\frac{11}{6}$ and the RHS is $\ge \frac{11}6$ with equality iff $x=3$. Thus we have found our first real root and shown that it is the largest: $x=3$.

If $x<0$, the LHS is negative, the RHS positive, hence we cannot find a real solution there.

If $2<x<3$, then the LHS is strictly decreasing from $+\infty$ to $\frac{11}6$ and the RHS strictly increasing from $\frac{22}{27}$ to $\frac{11}6$. We conclude that there is no real root with floor $2$.

Similarly, in the interval $(1,2)$ and in the interval $(0,1)$, the LHS goes from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$, whereas the RHS remains bounded. We conclude that in each of these intervals, there is *at least* one real root.

So far, we have found/shown the existence of one real root with $\lfloor x\rfloor =3$, one with $\lfloor x\rfloor =1$, one with $\lfloor x\rfloor =0$. 
If we trust the problem statement that a definite answer can be given at all, we thus see that the answer *must* be $$4.$$
But for a more satisfying nswer, we have to verify that there are no additional roots in $(0,1)$ and/or $(1,2)$ that would allow us to achieve a different sum with different picks of real roots.
One way you might try for this, is to show that in each of these intervals, the LHS is strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: use that $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{11}{54}x^2=-\frac{(x-3) \left(11 x^4+22 x^2-96 x+36\right)}{54 (x-2) (x-1) x}$$

Comment: That doesnt help a lot . Can you add more details?

Comment: why not? it is clear that $x=3$ is one solution and considering the quartic equation you can try to find another one and thank you for the $-1$

Comment: I didnt downvote. But I can nullify it.